# Why is :last-child not giving me the results I expect?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/_mtr/uqMZJ/

Basically, a table with rows, only 10 or so are not hidden when the document is ready. I want the index of the last non-hidden row, but my jQuery selectors are letting me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing the [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector, which matches elements that are the last child of their parent. You actually want the last element in the matched set, so you should use the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector instead:

```
i2 = $('table .visible:last').index();
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uqMZJ/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Because there is nothing (neither `<tbody>`nor `<tr>` nor `<td>`with the class `visible` that at the same time is the `table`'s last child.

You should use [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) instead, which selects the last matching element in a jquery collection.

Answer (score 0):

You' better use class selector at the end:

```
var i2 = $('table :last-child .visible').index();
```

Because `:last-child` applies to table.

Comment: "Because `:last-child` applies to table." What are you talking about?

Comment: I just meant what the OP needed is to get the *last child* of the table, not the last child of each `.visible`. My answer give the same results as @FredericHamidi's one.

Answer (score 0):

Last-child simply tells you that the element is the last child of the parent, not the last of the group matched by the preceding selector. None of the `tr.visible`s is the last child of the `table` tag. To get the last visible tr, try this instead:

```
$('tr.visible').last ();
```

That's what the "last" method is for :)